# Unable to backup mysql database using mysqldump(php code)

Tags: database, php-5.4

I am trying backup my mysql database of linux hosted website(remote server-cpanel account) using mysqldump and executing this code through php file(db_backup.php).

db_backup.php
{

exec('mysqldump --user=MYUSERNAME --password=MYPASSWORD --host=localhost MYDBNAME> \home\kmnazar\public_htm\db\file.sql')

?>
}

Unfortunately unable to produce any backup file.Please guide me to resolve the issue.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

try to use 
mysql -p -u username dbname < erecycler.net.sql   this command

for export 
mysqldump -u [database_user] -p [database_name] > backup_livestore.sql

use this command

Comment: I need to backup my db not to restore

Comment: check i update my answer.